# Electron `second-instance` event not being triggered for custom protocol redirect on Windows Server 2016 VM acting as GitHub Actions runner

Tags: electron

My Electron application uses OAuth and after logging in redirects to a custom protocol to handle the access token in the Main process. This works on a Windows 10 machine without issue but when I try to run the application during a GitHub Action on a Windows Server 2016 VM the redirect happens but the `second-instance` event never triggers so it does not handle the access token in the Main process.

I followed all of the documentation for setting up the custom protocol and capturing the command line via the `second-instance` event to trigger opening the URL correctly.

If I remote onto the Windows Server 2016 machine I encounter the same issue as when it is running as a job. However, if I trigger the protocol from a browser, it opens the app without issue. So, for some reason, specifically when the application tries to redirect from OAuth, it does not trigger the `second-instance` event despite `did-redirect-navigation` triggering with the custom protocol.

What would prevent this from happening?

Here is some example code:

```js
if (process.defaultApp) {
  if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('my-protocol', process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])])
  }
} else {
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('my-protocol')
}
```

```js
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    if (mainWindow) {
      if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
      mainWindow.focus()
    }
    
    // handle commandLine
  })

  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
  })
}
```